# Let $K=${$(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23),1$} .Prove that $K$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups

Now we need to prove that $gKg^{-1}=K$.So, we try to see the following that $g(12)(34)g^{-1}=g(1)g(2)g(3)g(4) \in K$.Although there are many hints to the problem,I particularly have a problem in one thing - If we take $g(1)g(2)$ as a cycle and $g(3)g(4)$ as a cycle then we try to find the number of possible $2-cycles$in $S_4$.

The possible 2-cycles are of the form $(ab)(cd)$ where the element $a$ has $4$ choices $b$ has $3$ choices .Now the $(ab)$ is the same as $(ba)$ , so we divide $(4×3)/2$ Similarly for the other part we get $(2×1)/2$ Now$(ab)(cd)$ has the same representation as $(cd)(ab)$so we divide the answer by $2$ to get $3$.Hence the number of cycles is .$3$ So they are in $K$.

Now my question is can we choose $g$ in such a way that the conjugate is a $4$ cycle .

Comment: No. Conjugation preserves the cycle structure.

Comment: No - to the $4-$cycle. The general idea that cycle structure in symmetric groups is preserved by conjugation is enough. But note that in any group conjugation preserves order, and a $4-$cycle has order $4$. Also a $4-$cycle is an odd permutation and conjugation preserves oddness/evenness ($g$ and $g^{-1}$ are both odd or both even).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An important equality in $\mathcal S_n$ is that if $(a_1 \ a_2 \dots \ a_k)$ is a cycle and $\sigma$ any element of $\mathcal S_n$ then

$$\sigma (a_1 \ a_2 \dots \ a_k) \sigma^{-1} = (\sigma(a_1) \ \sigma(a_2) \dots \ \sigma(a_k))$$

This is used in many areas when dealing with permutations.

Using that, you can prove that the cycle structure of any permutation is preserved by conjugacy.